# Whenever i start react after a day or so and try to start it gives error

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, npm

Whenever I start react after a day or so and try to start it gives error. Please tell me how to tackle this problem?

When I write `npm start` in the react app it gives me the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\Umang Rajpurohit\Documents\MERN> npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Umang Rajpurohit\Documents\MERN/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Umang Rajpurohit\Documents\MERN\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\cache\_logs\2021-06-29T09_19_50_071Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\Umang Rajpurohit\Documents\MERN> npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Umang Rajpurohit\Documents\MERN/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Umang Rajpurohit\Documents\MERN\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\cache\_logs\2021-06-29T09_21_08_415Z-debug.log
```

Comment: It looks like somewhere you have a slash instead of a back-slash: the system is looking for C:\...\MERN/package.json but the path is C:\...\MERN\package.json and the package.json file cannot be found.

Comment: so, after a day or so, it stops working ... does it start working all by itself, and then after a day stop again? is there anything in the complete log that is more useful than the info you posted?

Comment: @secan - nodejs on windows is smart enough to figure that out

Comment: Maybe sharing the content of the file C:\cache\_logs\2021-06-29T09_21_08_415Z-debug.log might help

Comment: Are you sure you're in the same directory you were the other day?

Comment: yes i was in the same directory

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have a `package.json` file. It should be in your root directory which is where you should do "npm start". I hope you don't have it in a subfolder like C:\Users\Umang Rajpurohit\Documents\MERN\boilerplate_created_folder\package.json.

If the above is not the issue then delete `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json`

then run `npm install`.

Kill "node" service from your task manager as well before restart preferably.

Comment: Thank you so much man it worked .God bless you brother Amen

Answer (score -1):

Possible fix:

Check first what you've typed in when running app. Normally, it must be a command like `npm start`.

`npm` tries to find entry point for you command in the scripts section of your `package.json` file (see [npm docs on scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) for details).

A `package.json`, simplified, describes your app's dependencies and environment.

As you don't have such command in `package.json`, `npm` fails with `ENOENT`, which is an abbreviation for Error NO ENTry.

Comment: look at the question ... OP runs the app using `npm start` - so, not sure how that helps :p